# Weird behavior on plotting parametric functions (or their corresponding datablock) when using lines

Tags: gnuplot

I have some weird behavior on plotting parametric functions and/or their corresponding datablock when using lines.
The plot seem don't obey the `linestyle` (row 1), at the same time the default `linetype` applied seems reversed when comparing plots come from functions or datablock (row 2).
Curiously the plot seems to inherit the `linewidth` from `linestyle` (row 3).
Only when using `linecolor` (row 4) the plots looks like correct.

[image: result]

Here are the code, tested under `5.2.8` and `5.4 rc1` versions:

```
reset

set terminal pngcairo size 750,9.0 font ",10"
set output "parametric.png"

unset tics
unset border
set view equal xyz
set view ,,2
set view 100,30
set xyplane 0
set hidden3d

set parametric
set urange [0:2*pi]
set vrange [0:pi/2]

set style line 1 lc "red" lw 2

f(u,v) = cos(u)*cos(v)
g(u,v) = sin(u)*cos(v)
h(v)   = sin(v)

set table $hemisphere
    splot f(u,v), g(u,v), h(v)
unset table

set multiplot layout 4,2 columnsfirst
    splot f(u,v), g(u,v), h(v) w l ls -1 t "Using functions (with ls -1 )"
    splot f(u,v), g(u,v), h(v) w l lt  3 t "Using functions (with lt 3)"
    splot f(u,v), g(u,v), h(v) w l ls  1 t "Using functions (with custom ls 1)"
    splot f(u,v), g(u,v), h(v) w l lc "red" t "Using functions (with lc 'red')"
    splot $hemisphere w l ls -1 t "Using datablock (with ls -1)"
    splot $hemisphere w l lt  3 t "Using datablock (with lt 3)"
    splot $hemisphere w l ls  1 t "Using datablock (with custom ls 1)"
    splot $hemisphere w l lc "red" t "Using datablock (with lc 'red')"
unset multiplot
```

Additionally, if you taken a close look on surface it has a reversed line segment.

[image: close 1]
[image: close 2]

What is happen here? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Basic reason:** 
From the docs (selected text from `help hidden3d`)

```
Syntax:
       set hidden3d {defaults} |
                    {{offset <offset>} | {nooffset}}
[...]

The first option, `offset`, influences the linetype used for lines on the
'back' side.  Normally, they are drawn in a linetype one index number higher
than the one used for the front, to make the two sides of the surface
distinguishable.  You can specify a different linetype offset to add
instead of the default 1, by `offset <offset>`.  Option `nooffset` stands for
`offset 0`, making the two sides of the surface use the same linetype.
```

Notice that there is no mention of linestyles, as opposed to linetypes. The hidden3d algorithm carries out a complicated process of assigning colors to individual line segments that is explicitly based on the numerical linetype.  Generation of the line sample in the key is more generic. It apparently fails to duplicate exactly what happens if `hidden3d` is active, so let's call that much a bug.

**Wrong color for one line segment:** I think this must be due to round-off error somewhere. Minute changes to the view angle or even to the terminal size cause the artifact to go away.

**Doesn't really help anything but explains why it is the way you see it:** In gnuplot 5 the use of linetypes pretty much supplemented the older mechanism of linestyles.  There is partial backwards compatibility via the command `set style increment user`, which triggers in many places where the program has to pick a color for the "next thing" whatever that might be.  But it doesn't catch all the places where the multiple colors are involved, and hidden3d is one of those places.

Comment: Thank you for explanation! Some odd behaviors are clear now. Maybe I didn't make myself clear. I had understood about coloring the back side of surface before. My question is: why a color is attributed to surface when a function is drawn and a reversed one when their corresponding datablock is plotted?

Comment: I understand the question, but I do not know the answer.  Work-around: since the front/back assignment depends on the order of the vertices defining each facet, you could flip the order for your particular plot by saying `splot $hemisphere using 2:1:3 with lines`. But that only works because the figure itself is symmetric

Comment: Well, at least now I know how to handle these issues to achieve the wanted results. Thank you again for shed light!